# Postgres command line tools on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I follow tutorial on Postgres 9.2 on postgres official site. They tell about `postgres` command, `createdb` command and so on. But I don't have them! I installed postgres with `sudo apt-get install postgres` on Ubuntu 12.04. Instead, I have brand new `psql` command.

Comment: Where are you looking for them?  And a link to the tutorial is missing...

Comment: Guess the PostgreSQL `bin` directory was not added to the `PATH`

Comment: I'd say you need to install `postgresql-server`; you probably only installed the client package.

Answer (score 1):

When you're lacking a command on Ubuntu and don't know what package to install, you can go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and type the command name in the **Search the contents of packages** section.

In the case of `createdb`, it comes with the **postgresql-client-common** for the soft link installed in `/usr/bin/createdb`, and **postgresql-client-9.1** for the actual binary that gets installed in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/createdb`

You need both packages.

However, if you already have a working `psql`, it normally means that you already have them installed, because it comes in the same packages.